# Unable leverage Browser Caching on AWS Bitnami stack (Apache) through W3TC and Cloudfront CDN

Tags: htaccess, cache, apache, plugin-w3-total-cache, cdn

I followed many tutorial about leveraging browser caching nevertheless I couldn't configure it succesfully, in fact GTmetric (PageSpeed and YSlow) notified me many static file that don't have a cache expire header.
That's my GTmetrix result (pagespeed):

[image]

I tried to find the problem looking at compatibility test on W3TC and it notified me many Apache modules missed which are required for browser caching:

[image]

I followed some tutorial to enable these modules but it seems they are alread enabled, in fact they are already uncommented on my [/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf](https://pastebin.com/yU3eZU2p)

This is my [.htaccess](https://pastebin.com/FJcWZeM4)

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration as you and I too have run into this problem.

Assuming that you have got the modules enabled (see below), I think you can safely ignore the results of this part of the compatibility test.

W3 Total Cache reports missing modules because mod_php is disabled by Bitnami due to their view that it is not secure.

From the [Bitnami AWS documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/troubleshooting/optimize-bitnami-wordpress/)

> During installation, W3 Total Cache may display an error stating that some Apache modules are not detected on the server, when they are in fact installed. This error is a known bug in the W3 Total Cache plugin and may be safely ignored.

This references a [Plesk article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005108854-W3-Total-Cache-plugin-shows-apache-modules-as-not-detected-)

> W3 Total Cache cannot read the state of an apache module if the website is not run with mod_php on a apache server. mod_php is disabled in Plesk by default because it is not secure (mod_php is outdated).

So just make sure you have uncommented all the required modules in  /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf. I used the list that W3TC says was "missing" as a reference for what I needed to uncomment.

Then restart your server to let the changes take affect: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart

In case it helps someone else, I was also confused as to why changes I made to the "Browser Cache" settings in W3TC didn't seem to have any affect. Specifically changing the "Expires header lifetime" under "Media & Other Files" didn't result in any change to the value that I'd see when examining the headers of the object in the browser.

I think this may be due to W3TC expecting to be able to modify the .htaccess file to put these values into operation, but instead [bitnami uses a single htaccess.conf file](https://community.bitnami.com/t/w3-total-cache-browser-caching-issue/54869/2)

> Bitnami stacks recollect all the htaccess information in a single file, /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf in your case and the AllowOverride option is set to None. Therefore, please add what you modified at /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/.htaccess to that file and then, restart Apache.

In otherwords, you need to manually change the values in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf